# Inserting Null Values for Dynamic Inputs Array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, mariadb

Using PHP Version 7.1.9, MariaDB 10.1.26.

I'm submitting an array of form data to a MySQL database. The form allows the addition of dynamic inputs, when the dynamic inputs are added they look like this;

```
// I have removed additional html form code for brevity
<input type="text" name="mac[]">
<input type="text" name="mac[]">
<input type="text" name="mac[]">
etc...
```

Sometimes these inputs will be empty, this is allowed. When the inputs are empty, I want to insert a `NULL` value into my database. This is where I'm having issues.

I have ensured that my database table is set to;

- allow null = yes
- default - null

My PHP code for handling the form submission is below *(please ignore any security vulnerabilities this is simplified code)*;

```
// I have removed additional php code for brevity
$arr_mac = $_POST['mac'] ? "'".$_POST['mac']."'" : 'NULL';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_mac); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES ( ".$arr_mac[$i]." )
}
```

The error I receive is;

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax.. ..

When I `var_dump(mac)` I get;

```
[mac] => Array
  (
    [0] =>
    [1] => 
    [2] =>  
  )
```

If I change the PHP to the following (notice the additional `' '`) in the insert, the query runs successfully, **but** instead of `null` values, `empty` values are inserted into the database.

```
$arr_mac = $_POST['mac'] ;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_mac); $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES (' ".$arr_mac[$i]." ')
}
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full generated query?

Comment: I think you must literally insert `NULL`, if the value is null: `$sql = "INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES (" . ($arr_mac[$i] ? "'{$arr_mac[$i]}'" : 'NULL') . ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you build your query in the wrong syntax. Using the given code, your `INSERT` might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES ()
```

Your code does not handle the `NULL` case properly - having a variable set to `NULL` does not result in using the literal `NULL` for building the query.

This might help:

```
$arr_mac = $_POST['mac'] ? "'".$_POST['mac']."'" : 'NULL';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_mac); $i++) {
    $value = $arr_mac[$i];
    if(!$value) {
        $value = 'NULL';
    } else {
        $value = your_favorite_escaping_algorithm($value);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES ( ". $value ." )";
}
```

This helps writing out that specific `NULL` value you need for a syntactically correct query

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_mac = $_POST['mac'] ;
$batchInsert = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_mac); $i++) {
    if( "" == trim($arr_mac[$i])) {
        $arr_mac[$i] = 'NULL';
    }
       $batchInsert = array_push($arr_mac[$i]);
}
$insertValues = implode("','", $batchInsert)
$sql = "INSERT INTO staff (mac) VALUES ('$batchInsert')";
```

***check ' and , formation using implode function

This will insert N no. of values in single INSERT statement, will execute much faster!

Comment: Are you sure about that? How does this add the requested `NULL` values to the database?

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase for highlighting, I pasted wrong snipped from my notepad!